# SELECT with JOIN And SUM in JPQL

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpql

I wanna do a query for extract information in a dashboard. I have two entities: User and Post, they are a manytomany relation. In my query, I wanna get the post information and the number of users by rol in each post.

I have tried this query, and it is working, but when there is a post without users, it isn't coming in the resultset, and it should be "| post1 | information | 0 | 0 |".

```
    @Query("SELECT new com.project.dto.DashboardDTO("
        + "post.title, "
        + "post.information, "
        + "SUM(CASE WHEN u.rol = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), "
        + "SUM(CASE WHEN u.rol = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) "
        + "FROM Post post JOIN post.users u "
        + "GROUP BY post.title, post.information")
   Page<DashboardDTO> getDashboard(Pageable pageable);
```

What have I to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `left join` instead of `join`, and you'll get the desired result.

Also if you need to get the summarization details for each post, you can group by the post id instead of (title, information) because both of them functionally depend on the id.
The query would be:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.project.dto.DashboardDTO("
        + "post.title, "
        + "post.information, "
        + "SUM(CASE WHEN u.rol = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), "
        + "SUM(CASE WHEN u.rol = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) "
        + "FROM Post post LEFT JOIN post.users u "
        + "GROUP BY post")
Page<DashboardDTO> getDashboard(Pageable pageable);
```